# SQL Server Error - Msg 116

Tags: sql-server-2014

My query is as follows, and contains a subquery within it:

```
SELECT       
    dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitNUM, dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitYear,
    dbo.Groups.GroupName, dbo.LawsuitType.LawsuitType,
    dbo.Courts.CourtName,
    (select 
         LawsuitID, DOJ, NextMeeting, ReceiptNUM, ExportNUM, ExportDate
     from 
         (select   
              dbo.LawsuitExport.LawsuitID, 
              dbo.LawsuitExport.DOJ,
              dbo.LawsuitExport.NextMeeting,
              dbo.LawsuitExport.ReceiptNUM,
              dbo.LawsuitExport.ExportNUM,
              dbo.LawsuitExport.ExportDate,
              row_number() over(partition by dbo.LawsuitExport.LawsuitID 
                                order by dbo.LawsuitExport.ExportDate desc) as rn
          from 
              dbo.LawsuitExport) as T 
       where 
           rn = 1)
FROM    
    dbo.Courts 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LawsuitType ON dbo.Courts.CourtID = dbo.LawsuitType.CourtID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Groups ON dbo.LawsuitType.LawsuitTypeID = dbo.Groups.LawsuitTypeID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lawsuit ON dbo.Groups.GroupID = dbo.Lawsuit.GroupID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LawsuitExport ON dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitID = dbo.LawsuitExport.LawsuitID
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The line 
`select LawsuitID,DOJ,NextMeeting,ReceiptNUM,ExportNUM,ExportDate` doesnt work because you can only have 1 item returned from a sub query when it is trying to be used in another select statement. For example

`SELECT X FROM Y` GOOD

`SELECT X, (SELECT A,B,C FROM FOO) FROM Y` NOT GOOD

`A,B,C` cannot be mapped to 1 single element so that is invalid

Comment: I do not want to repeat rows so use the second Select of choice - where they choose the latest date in like-data with each other

Answer (score 0):

If that's what is your intention then consider modifying your query like

```
SELECT       
    dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitNUM, dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitYear,
    dbo.Groups.GroupName, dbo.LawsuitType.LawsuitType,
    dbo.Courts.CourtName,XXX.LawsuitID, XXX.DOJ, XXX.NextMeeting, XXX.ReceiptNUM, XXX.ExportNUM, XXX.ExportDate
FROM    
    dbo.Courts 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LawsuitType ON dbo.Courts.CourtID = dbo.LawsuitType.CourtID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Groups ON dbo.LawsuitType.LawsuitTypeID = dbo.Groups.LawsuitTypeID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lawsuit ON dbo.Groups.GroupID = dbo.Lawsuit.GroupID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LawsuitExport ON dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitID = dbo.LawsuitExport.LawsuitID
INNER JOIN (select   
              LawsuitID, 
              DOJ,
              NextMeeting,
              ReceiptNUM,
              ExportNUM,
              ExportDate,
              row_number() over(partition by LawsuitID 
                                order by ExportDate desc) as rn
          from 
              dbo.LawsuitExport) XXX ON dbo.Lawsuit.LawsuitID = XXX.LawsuitID
WHERE XXX.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I do not want to repeat rows so use the second Select of choice - where they choose the latest date in like-data with each other